# Custom shipping method - Physical store address in checkout?

Tags: php, store, checkout, magento2

I'm working on a custom shipping method and I need to retrieve the physical store address inside the collectRates method in order to calculate the shipping price.

I managed to retrieve the current store this way :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$store = $storeManager->getStore();
```

But it seem that it's not the physical store, only the online store.

Does someone know how to retrieve the adress, the post code and the city ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found it.

It may interest someone so I will post the solution here.

You only have to call the getConfig method with the field you want to retrieve.

In order to retrieve the street address first line, you have to do it like this :

```
$store->getConfig('general/store_information/street_line1');
```

You can find the list of the differents fields on the [magento github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/077584c99ebb8007cad176c3b9a0144a05c259cd/app/code/Magento/Store/Model/Information.php)